# Use distinct and where clause in Elasticsearch Query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to get result from `Elasticsearch` as Sql Query

```
select distinct(id) from table where E_id in (5,6) and P_id=54
```

I manged to build block of code to get distinct values using aggregates in elasticsearch as follows

```
GET /Index/Type/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "my_fields": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ID",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I have another block of code which does `where` clause job of `SQL` query

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {            
            "must": [
               {
                  "terms": {
                    "ID": [ "5","6" ]          
                  }
                },
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "ProjectID": [ "54"]
                  }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I integrate these two blocks and get distinct result with `where` clause in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Just combine both `query` and `aggregation`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "ID": [
              "5",
              "6"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "ProjectID": [
              "54"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_fields": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ID",
        "size": 0
      },
    "aggs":{
      "top_hits_log"   :{
       "top_hits"   :{
           "size" :1
       }
      }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Study about `top_hits` [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

Comment: Yeah I just did same thing..thanx bdw :)

Comment: Hey its not working properly...when I run this query I get without distinct records..like **select id from table where E_id in (5,6) and P_id=54** and I expecting **select distinct(id) from table where E_id in (5,6) and P_id=54**..such sort of result

Comment: What output are you getting? Please specify.

Comment: I expecting distinct records and with query which you've given me it returning duplicate records too

Comment: In `hits` or in `aggregation buckets` ?

Comment: You have to fetch distinct ids from `aggregation buckets` not from `hits`.

Comment: but `aggregation buckets` returns distinct Id only..I need other information too which I get in `hits`

Comment: Both the hits are different in themselves. Both will have different data. How can you expect one document to be displayed and other not. Even in sql you do only `distinct(ids)` not `distinct(records)`.

Comment: What other fields you want to be displayed?

Comment: Id and other information it would be anything like name, address, etc.

Comment: But which name and address you would take , if it exists in multiple documents?? This is my question to you?

Comment: The result we get from `SQL` when we use `select distinct(id),* from table` such result m expecting from `ES`

Comment: Have you tried running `select distinct(id),* from table`  in sql. I doesn't even work

Comment: You can use `top_hits` aggregation with size 1 . It will return all other data. Edited my answer.

Comment: This should not happen. `top_hits` is just a subaggregation. It should not affect existing data.